# How to display a link on my page

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image]
I want to display google link like that in my page.
whenever we post a link on a Facebook page its look like as the above picture. how to do the same in my webpage .how to display the google link like that

Comment: question is totally unclear

Comment: whenever we post a link on a Facebook page its look like as the above picture. how to do the same in my webpage .how to display the google link like that

Comment: You are looking for the Google Favicon 2015?

Comment: no no i want to display the link like that

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a link shared on Facebook. The styling of a link like that doesn't happen automatically. You'll have to use html and css to format a link to look like that yourself.

Here's an example using pseudo html. You'd need to actually style this yourself to achieve the desired result. If you don't know how, some websites to start learning html / css are codecademy.com & w3schools.com

```
<a href="link_url">
  <img src="google_logo_url" />
  <div>
    <h3>Google</h3>
    <p>Search the world's information....</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed.ly can be useful for you. It takes a URL and generates a piece of code, which you can paste in your HTML document to get similar look to that of your picture. Below is an example of its code in usage

[image: Demo]

From this link you can access it for free: http://embed.ly/code

Comment: didn't I tell. You have to paste the URL of the page in the input box and click embed. Then copy the generated code to your HTML document

Comment: and what about if the link is dynamic

Comment: i don't know what dynamic link means

Comment: if the links are come from database

Comment: For then I don't know. Maybe you should check embed.ly for that.